# Merging two disconnected graphs

Tags: graphs, machine-learning, statistics, kernel-functions

Firstly, I'd like to apologize for any misused terms or ways I could have made the description much more succinct. It's been a while since I took machine learning during my bachelor's.

I have two disconnected, directed graphs that I am attempting to merge together. Each node in the graph represents a set of data. Each edge is a member of the data set that is used by the kernel.

For each node in `DG1` I am comparing it to each node in `DG2` into graph `DG3`. I compare the data sets of the node via a kernel and determine a similarity confidence. Beyond a given confidence I can merge the two nodes into DG3.

The issue that I'm having is, let's consider two sets of nodes in each of DG1 and DG2 such that:

`DG1,N1 -> DG1,N2` (Node1 of Disconnected Graph 1 connects to Node2 of Disconnected Graph 1)

`DG2,N1 -> DG2,N2`

When trying to determine if `DG1,N1` and `DG2,N1` are similar, I need to take into account their connections. If `DG1,N2` and `DG2,N2` are to be merged (or similar enough), then that makes it more likely that `DG1,N1` and `DG2,N1` are similar. If `DG1,N2` and `DG2,N2` are not similar, then it makes it less likely that `DG1,N1` and `DG2,N1` are similar.

If this is the only connection it's relatively trivial. If the kernel is a function the ratio of the sum the similarities for each property in each node to the sum of all properties in both nodes, then I can just add the resulting value of `kernel(<DG1,N2> ,<DG2,N2>)` (where '1' would be the result if they are identical).

The problem that I have is (and I bet this is a common one), what to do with cycles? In this instance, where:

`DG1,N2 -> DG1,N1`

`DG2,N2 -> DG2,N1`

I've considered simply ignoring the edges (subtracting the value both from the sum of similarities and sum of every property), calculating a similarity, putting this value into the kernel and re-applying. This sounds to me like it could be represented as something similar to a Markov chain, in which I continually reapply this method to itself until it converges.

So I guess my question boils down to: Is there a way of determining a convergent probability that two nodes are similar? Is there a simple way this can be represented/calculated, possibly by something similar to a Markov chain?

Comment: Is *clustering* (cf Wikipedia) what you are trying to do?

Comment: "Each node in the graph represents a set of data. Each vertex is a one-way connection from one set of data to another." Node and vertex are synonyms. Do you mean that each edge (aka arc) is a one-way connection?

Comment: Sorry, yes edge. And I'm not necessarily trying to cluster them, though the more I research the more it could be seen that way. What I'm really trying to do is create clusters of maximum size 2 which contain at most one item from each graph. Then, combining those clusters into a single node. The problem is that the calculation for this clustering can rely on clustering already have been done (in the case of a cycle), so I need to know how best to find a convergent similarity measure which takes into account clusters that have already been created.

Comment: I think the first step of the algorithm will likely be pruning and combining "easy" targets which are not part of cycles, then processing each cycle independently.

Comment: Currently I'm reading this paper, as I think that it can be related to synonym extraction. If you consider each directed graph as a lexicon, then two nodes being similar is equal to saying that they are synonymous. This also means that the default "one-synonym" implementation is possibly exactly what I need. After reading a bit more it seems that this is based on pathing which seems more optimized for lexical evaluation. It still looks like a good starting point.